# Cumulative difference In R

Tags: r, vector, difference, cumulative-sum

What is the opposite of `cumsum()` in R

```
a = c(2, 5, 8)
cumsum = c(2, 7, 15)
cumdiff = c(2, 3, 1)
```

Because 5-2 = 3 and 8-7 = 1.

Is there a package that can be used for this one in R?

Comment: `c(a[1],a[-1] - cumsum(a)[-length(a)])`

Comment: @maydin please post as an answer.

Comment: @zx8754 I thought at first,  but it is not so different from the answers below. Just one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `base R`:

```r
cumdiff <- function(x) x - head(c(0, cumsum(x)), -1)
#cumdiff <- function(x) x - c(0, cumsum(x))[-(length(x) + 1)]
```

In `dplyr`, with `lag` and `default = 0`:

```r
library(dplyr)
cumdiff <- function(x) x - lag(cumsum(x), default = 0)
```

Result:

```r
a = c(2,5,8)
cumdiff(a)
#[1] 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If by cumdiff you mean the current value in the vector minus the cumsum of the previous values, you could use the below:

```r
a = c(2,5,8)
cumdiff <- function(x){
  out <- x - lag(cumsum(x))
  out[1] <- x[1]
  return(out)
}
cumdiff(a)
[1] 2 3 1


library(dplyr)
tibble(a) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(a),
         cumdiff = cumdiff(a))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       a cumsum cumdiff
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     2      2       2
#> 2     5      7       3
#> 3     8     15       1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So if cumdiff[1] cannot be stated as the fst row in a?

Comment: Techincally you can't compute the cumdiff for the first one, but if you want you still want to return the starting value you could edit the code as below:

`cumdiff <- function(x){
  out <- x - lag(cumsum(x))
  out[1] <- x[1]
  return(out)
}cumdiff(a)

tibble(a = c(2,5,8)) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(a),
         cumdiff = cumdiff(a))`

I've edited my answer so you it returns the first value as you wished

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(a)  %>% 
  mutate(
         cumdiff = a - lag(cumsum(a)),
         cumdiff = ifelse(is.na(cumdiff), a, cumdiff)
         )
  a cumdiff
1 2       2
2 5       3
3 8       1
```